# Topics in Banach space theory

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a subspace of a space with unconditional basis. Show that if $X$ contains no copy of $c_0$ or $l_1$ then $X$ is reflexive.

We know that a Banach space is reflexive iff it has a basis which is both boundedly complete and shrinking.

If we have $X$ as a space with unconditional basis then since $X$ doesn't have a copy of $c_0$ so the basis is boundedly complete and since $X$ doesn't have a copy of $l_1$, the basis is shrinking. Now since basis is both shrinking and boundedly complete $X$ is reflexive.

But the problem is that I don't know if we can say $X$ has unconditional basis

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have such a result, regarding subspaces? If not then you cannot say it (unless you can prove it, if you think it is true).

Comment: I don't know if a space have unconditional basis then we can say it's subspace have unconditional basis

Comment: No, the subspace may not even have a basis. Your result is mentioned in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975644?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (Theorem 8.1) with a reference to its proof. (I imagine, though, that the proof relies on "property u", discussed in Kalton-Albiac.)

Comment: I tried searching for the paper: On subspaces of a space with an absolute basis by Bessaga, C.; Pełczyński, A but can't find it if any of you have it please share. @DavidMitra
 Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is Exercise 3.6 in Kalton and Albiac's *Topics in Banach Space theory*.

The result, and its proof can be found in the paper
*On bases and unconditional convergence of series in Banach spaces*,
C. Bessaga, A. Pełczyński, Studia Mathematica 17 (1958), 151-164. This paper will henceforth be denoted by $[1]$, and can be found [here](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/studia-mathematica/all/17).

The result follows immediately from the main results of this paper:

1) Since $X$ contains no copy of $c_0$, it must be weakly sequentially complete (every weakly Cauchy sequence in $X$ is weakly convergent).

and

2) Since $X$ does not contain a copy of $\ell_1$, every bounded sequence in            $X$ has a weakly Cauchy subsequence.

Combining these, it follows that every bounded sequence in $X$ has a weakly  convergent subsequence. By the Eberlein–Šmulian theorem, then, the closed unit ball of $X$ is weakly compact; and so, $X$ is reflexive. 
$${}$$
The proof of 1) given in $[1]$ is somewhat intimidating; but I imagine a simplified proof of 1) (which is likely what  Kalton and Albiac had in mind) is contained in the reference of the James' paper mentioned in the comments.

1) follows from  the fact that $X$ must have property $(u)$, as defined in Definition 3.5.1 of Kalton/Albiac. It follows from the definition of property $(u)$ that if $X$ had a weakly Cauchy sequence that was not weakly convergent, then $X$ would have a WUC (weakly unconditionally Cauchy) series that is not convergent. This would imply that $X$ must contain a copy of $c_0$ (Theorem 2.4.11 in Kalton/Albiac).

2) follows immediately from Rosenthal's $\ell_1$-theorem: a Banach space $X$ does not contain a copy of $\ell_1$ iff every bounded sequence in $X$ has a weakly Cauchy subsequence.   This is a bit of a sledgehammer, of course; in [1],  the $\ell_1$-theorem is proved for a Banach space $X$ that is a subspace of a space with an unconditional basis (this proof can  be reproduced using results from Kalton/Albiac prior to this exercise).